# Building block does not work if someone changes the location template

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word, buildingblocks

In vba word. I have a .dotm template file with content blocks. The path in the content blocks works if the .dotm file is in that path.

```
Application.Templates( _
        "**L:\06. MODELOS DE DOCUMENTOS\01 ATESTADOS\ACCIDENTES DE CIRCULACIÓN\BAEI\Informe Tecnico\BAEI - INFORME TÉCNICO.dotm**"). _
        BuildingBlockEntries("INICIO Y EXPOSICION DE HECHOS").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText _
        :=True
```

If someone takes the .dotm template file to another path, the content blocks no longer work.

Is it possible to create a macro that asks the user where to save the .dotm template file and substitutes the new path in the code?

Comment: Cross posted at https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/48688-content-blocks-stop-working-when-changing-file.html with extensive responses. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 1):

### Put the building block and the macro in the same template.

Then you can use `ThisDocument.Fullname` as the location in your code for the building block. This and other possibilities are explored in [my page on building blocks](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock).

This question is cross-posted. Much more extensive exploration of the possibilities and problems in the [other forum](https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/48688-content-blocks-stop-working-when-changing-file.html). Please see [A message to forum cross-posters](https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184).